# how to retrieve date from PdfDictionary

Tags: itext, itextpdf

in a signed PDF
in the FILTER dictionary of the PROP_BUILD dictionary of the SignatureDictionary are 4 keys

```
/Date
/Name
/V
/R
```

As there is no PdfName.DATE, how can I retrieve the date from this point which I know exists, as it can be seen with RUPS?

Answer (score 2):

RUPS crawls throug a PDF using methods such as `getAsDict()`, `getAsNumber()`, and so on. But everything starts with the `getCatalog()` method, which give you the root dictionary of a PDF.

This is all explained in chapter 13 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book), but if you don't own a copy of that book, you can already benefit from the [examples of chapter 13](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=13) entitled **PDFs inside-out**.

For instance: take a look at the [`FixBrokenForm`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=236) example:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
PdfDictionary form = root.getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);
```

In this example, we get the `root` dictionary from the `reader` using the `getCatalog()` method. We get the `/AcroForm` dictionary using the `getAsDict()` method and the `/Fields` array using the `getAsArray()` method.

Insidentally, this already brings you very close to what you need, as one of the dictionaries in the `/Fields` array will be the signature field dictionary:

```
PdfDictionary signatureField = fields.getAsDict(i);
```

In the line above `i` is the index of your signature field (it is for you to find out which of all entries in the `/Fields` array is the signature field you're looking for).

Once you have the `signatureField`, you can get the signature dictionary like this:

```
PdfDictionary sigDict = signatureField.getAsDict(PdfName.V);
```

From there on, you can further examine all the entries in the signature dictionary.

Note that there's also a short cut to get straight to the signature field dictionary using the `AcroField.Item` class. For more info, take a look at the [`InspectForm`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=237) example. However, as you explicitly referred to RUPS, I thought you'd want to know how RUPS works internally and that's why I started at the root dictionary.

Comment: as ever, helpful pointers... works with get(PdfName.PROP_BUILD).get(PdfName.FILTER).get(new PdfName('Date'))

Comment: What is the Key name in PdfName.class called "/slns_fsize" to get fontsize ?@Bruno